# Model object not getting values in controller actionMethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http-post, actionmethod

I'm new to Asp.Net MVC. I am facing this issue that I have strongly typed input fields in  view file. When I send ajax call to controller acion-method, model objects do not get any value. My code is attached.

**View Code**

```
@model Swift_MT_103.Models.MT102_Dynamic
@{
ViewBag.Title = "MT102Appl";
}

  @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.accountNo_50k_1, "accountNo_50k_1", new { @class="form-control",@name= "accountNo_50k_1", @id= "accountNo_50k_1" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.accountTitle_50k_2, "accTitle", new {@name = "accTitle", @id = "accountTitle1"})                                  
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.branchCode_50k_3, "branchcode", new { @name = "accountNo", @id = "branchcode1"})
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.misc_150k_4, "MiscInfo1", new { @class = "form-control",@name = "MiscInfo1", @id = "MiscInfo1" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.misc_250k_5, "MiscInfo2", new { @class = "form-control"@name = "MiscInfo2", @id = "MiscInfo2" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.accountNo_59_1, "BenAccNo", new { @class = "form-control" @name = "BenAccNo", @id = "BenAccNo" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.accountTitle_59_2, "BenAccTitle", new {  @class = "form-control", @name = "BenAccTitle", @id = "BenAccTitle" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.branchCode_59_3, "BenBranchCode", new { @class = "form-control"@name = "BenBranchCode", @id = "BenBranchCode" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.misc_159_4, "BenMiscInfo1", new { @class = "form-control",@name = "BenMiscInfo1", @id = "BenMiscInfo1" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.misc_259_5, "BenMiscInfo2", new { @class = "form-control", @name = "BenMiscInfo2", @id = "BenMiscInfo2" })
```

**Button Code**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add">Add</button>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
  $("#add").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/MT102/SaveData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
            });
        });
```

**Controller Code**

```
 MT102_Dynamic obj = new MT102_Dynamic();
   [HttpPost]
    public void SaveData(MT102_Dynamic model) {
        var tmp = obj.accountNo_50k_1;

    }
```

When I use debugger and try to watch values it only shows null values. Help needed.

Comment: First thing: when using `@Html.TextBoxFor` don't also specify `@name=` and `@id=` as these will be set to the correct values automatically (there are scenarios when this is required, but not for a basic form).  Use just: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.accountNo_50k_1, new { @class="form-control" })`

Comment: You aren't sending any data in the ajax

Comment: Next thing: your POST doesn't post the form.  You could either serialise the form or just use `$("form").submit()` (assuming you put your controls in a form, which you haven't in this example) **edit** What @charlietfl said...

Comment: @charlietfl How to send model object through ajax? I am using model Swift_MT_103.Models.MT102_Dynamic. Isn't it supposed to implicitly map values to controller object?

Comment: No model exists in the browser...just the html your view generates. The browser has no idea what back end technology you use and doesn't care. Suggest you study some ajax tutorials

Comment: @charlietfl plz guide me how to send this model object containing values through ajax request.

Comment: As a side note - its just `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.accountNo_50k_1, new { @class="form-control" })` etc. - the rest of your arguments are pointless - you really need to understand what the `HtmlHelper` methods overloads are and what html they generate

Answer (score 0):

You're ajax code nothing post to the server. Either you can include the controls inside a form tag (`@Html.BeginForm`) and you can submit the form else read the values from jQuery and post with your ajax.

See the ajax example.

```
 var task = {
        ProjectId: $('#ddlProjects').val(),
        TaskNumber: $('#txtTaskNumber').val(),  
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Tasks/UpdateTask',
        type: 'POST',
        data: task,
        success: function (result) {
            // success result here
        },
        error: function () {
            // error result here   
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Ajax you are not passing data , use this it will help you

```
  var req = {
                    accountNo_50k_1: "50", //The property name 
                    branchCode_50k_3:"300"
                }

$.ajax({
                    url: '/MT102/SaveData', //Hope Your URL Is Correct 
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: req,
                    dataType: "json",
                   // async: true, By default,  all requests are sent asynchronously
                    success: function (result) {

                        if (result != null) {



                        }
                    },
                    error: function (e) {

                    }
                });
```